# Trying to get easting and northing points to be visible in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm a complete beginner on QGIS.
I have a load of Ordnance Survey NGRs which I have converted to eastings and northings of 5 digits each, imported them as a csv file into QGIS and tried to create them as a layer so that the individual site locations are visible.  The only other layer I have is a simple outline of the UK (OS high water polyline). The layer with the eastings and northings is at the top of the layers panel, but they are not showing up.  They are set to show up as simple coloured markers.
The project is set to OSGB 1936 (EPSG: 27700).

Any ideas where the location markers might be and how to make them visible?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your data including field names? What method did you use to import the csv?

Comment: I used delimited text in the data source manager, having created the csv file in Excel

Comment: And how are the coordinate fields formatted? Are they in separate fields? When you import them are you decaring which field is X and Y and declaring the coordinate system of the coordinates themselves and not of the project (if they are different)

Comment: You mention that your coords are 5 digits long, Eastings and Northings are typically 6 digits long. How did you convert the grid references?

Comment: Either your points are for some reason not visible, or they have ended up in another area (been there, done it) Select both layers, right click on one of them and do a "Zoom to layer", then you will see it if it ended up in the wrong area - there are a lot of reasons that could make that happen.

Comment: Also, would it be possible for you to upload (some of) your data or show a sample here. Preferably with an explanation of where you would expect them to end up.

Comment: Thank you for your replies everyone!  I think I have it fixed.  Looks like I needed to check that all the imported data, .shp files and delimited text were set to OSGB1936.  Doing that seems to have made them visible.  Phew!  Rookie error.